# Jenkins svn commit post-build

Tags: svn, commit, jenkins, post-build

I'm trying to make a post-build commit in Jenkins CI when it's succeeded.

Is there a way to make this?

My problem is that when i build it generates some dll's in the workspace that i need to commit to the svn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the build technology (e.g. Ant, Maven, MSBuild or FianlBuilder) you use for building your source code. To check-in your build results into your svn, you should add some new steps at the end of your build scripts. This step will simply add your build results to svn. For example your step may contain:

svn commit --file build-output.1 build-output.2

It should be noted that some build technologies are equipped with build-in tasks or actions for working with svn.

Comment: Thanks. I was hopping that jenkins had some king off trigger(plugins, task) to activate for that job. By the way, I'm using MSbuild.

Comment: This does not work because of missing credentials.

Comment: @DavidL.Then you should use `--username` and `--password` switches with your svn command.