# Commit files to SVN after build in jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I want to commit my compiled files to SVN after a successful build in Jenkins.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Did you have a look to this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105070/commit-file-from-jenkins-workspace-to-svn/28110156#28110156

Answer (score 1):

Try the [SVN Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher) for Jenkins.